# How to use SCARD_CTL_CODE under linux?

Tags: linux, smartcard, pcsc

I'm trying on some code to use ACR83 reader under Linux. I have successfully installed and tested `pcsc` and `ccid` drivers on my Ubuntu and also I can send/receive APDUs to my smart card. I was trying to use reader's LCD and Pinpad by a piece of code I have previousely tested on MS Windows successfully but each time I use a definition using `IOCTL_SMARTCARD_READ_KEY` I get an error on make saying: `undefined reference to SCARD_CTL_CODE`!!!

what is the diference between these definitions on Windows and Linux?

Should I change any thing?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/reader_8h.html).

If you define `#define SCARD_CTL_CODE(code) (0x42000000 + (code))` your source will be compatible for different platforms, as mentioned in the link above.